# What if I never create new object but keep adding the old object into the List by just updating it's value

Tags: c#, list

In a for loop, instead of declaring a new object and add it to my List, I just update the value of the old object and every time keep adding this old object to my List, why after a few loops all List elements become the same

```
foreach (vg_ts_VesselCashflow_CashFlow_Entity item in cashflow)
{
    var result = new VslMonthlyCashflow_Record();
    result.CapitalCost = item.CapitalCost;
    result.CharterRevenue = item.CharterRevenue;
    result.Date = item.Period;
    result.DryDock = item.DryDock;

    resultList.Add(result);
}
if (resultList != null)
    return resultList;
```

//Compared with this:

```
var result = new VslMonthlyCashflow_Record();
foreach (vg_ts_VesselCashflow_CashFlow_Entity item in cashflow)
{
    result.CapitalCost = item.CapitalCost;
    result.CharterRevenue = item.CharterRevenue;
    result.Date = item.Period;
    result.DryDock = item.DryDock;

    resultList.Add(result);
}
```

I expect my resultList to be updated but if I keep using the old object, when it loops 123 times, all elements in the List will be the same.

Comment: Objects are reference type and here you are not creating new object, you are just updating the values in same object.

Answer (score 4):

`List#Add` doesn't copy the object or anything like that, it just keeps a reference to the object you passed to it. In the second snippet, you keep adding the same object to the list multiple times. Each modification you perform on the object is visible through all the references pointing to it, including the local `result` variable and all the elements of the list.